# Passing an array to matlab from .NET(C#)

Tags: .net, arrays, matlab, c#-4.0

I have a matlab function

```
function arr = testcs(arg)
arr = [arg(1) + 1, arg(2) + 2;1 0];
```

which is compiled to test.dll within the class `dotnetclass`

I am accessing this testcs function in C#/WPF:

```
dotnetclass dc = new dotnetclass();
MWArray[] b = {1,2};
MWArray[] res = null;

try
{
    dc.testcs(1,ref res,b);
    double[,] native1 = (double[,])(res[0].ToArray());
    result.Text = native1[0,0].ToString();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

I am getting an error message at the line `dc.testcs(1,ref res,b);` as

```
MWMCR::EvaluateFunction error... Too many input arguments...
```

What could be the cause of the error?
I have tried

```
dc.testcs(2,ref res,b);
```

but the same error message comes.

Comment: Why do you think dc.testcs needs three arguments?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, The intellisense is suggesting it as one of the options.